# Change of basis innclusing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm asked to find the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and i know that i have to write the co-ordinates of vectors from $\alpha $   w.r.t to $\beta$ but i can do that only for vectors ,

Here i'm given two basises of $\mathbb{R^{2*2}}$ matrix.

$\alpha =$ $(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\-1& 2 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\-1& 2 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 2 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\-1& 0 \end{bmatrix})$

$\beta = $ $(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\1& 0 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0& 1 \end{bmatrix})$

In asnwer i have a $4*4$ matrix and i can't find out how do you write co-ordinates if the basises are in matrices? If it was a vector then i could write co-ordinate but i don't know how to do with matrices? and How we go from $2*2$ matrices to a $4*4$ matrix?

Can someone give me a tip? 
Thanks

Comment: Just think of the matrices as a element of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$\alpha=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\}$

$\beta=\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4\}$

then:

$$\alpha_1=1\cdot \beta_1-1\cdot\beta_2+2\cdot\beta_3+2\cdot\beta_4$$

and so on for the others basis vectors:

$$\alpha_2=3\cdot \beta_1-1\cdot\beta_2+2\cdot\beta_3+1\cdot\beta_4$$

$$\alpha_3=1\cdot \beta_1+2\cdot\beta_2-3\cdot\beta_3-1\cdot\beta_4$$

$$\alpha_4=2\cdot \beta_1-1\cdot\beta_2+0\cdot\beta_3+1\cdot\beta_4$$

Then you can construct the matrix $A$ which columns are the component of $\alpha_i$ vectors with respect to $\beta$ basis:

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}1 &3 & 1& 2\\-1&-1&2&-1\\ 2&2&-3&0\\2&1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

such that given any vector/matrix with component $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ in the basis 
 $\alpha$ we can easily find its expression in base $\beta$:

$$v=x_1\cdot\alpha_1+x_2\cdot\alpha_2+x_3\cdot\alpha_3+x_4\cdot\alpha_4=Ax$$

and viceversa given any vector/matrix in the basis $\beta$
we can find its expression in base $\alpha$ by:

$$x=A^{-1}v$$

Comment: I know that linear combinations from $\beta$ should return vectors from $\alpha$ but i here i have also a standard basis but i don't understand how do you make those combinations because $\alpha_1$ for example is a matrix

Comment: Here i'm given one standard basis so i'm trying to find a way such that i can construct a marix from $\beta$ to $\alpha$ and then take it's inverse. When we have vector then simply write them as colums in our matrix because co-ordinate of a vector with respect to it's standard basis are same but i don't know how can we do same with matrices.

Comment: let consider the matrix as a vector $(a_{11}, a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{12})$